# Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory' in '\ClientApp' @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 5:0-95

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core-2.0, angular2-aot

I have a asp.net core 2 app which is hosting the angular app. When running locally, everything works fine. But when I try to publish this to azure, I get the following error:

Module not found(0,0): Error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.module.browser.ngfactory' in '\ClientApp'
     @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 5:0-95

Found some issues that were reported on GitHub and tried the solutions. some of them are :

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1293
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5329#issuecomment-289173951

Still having the issue. Anyone faced this and was able to resolve it?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? it's still a problem for me

Comment: Nope. Moved to template from. Net core 2.1.  That works great

Answer (score -2):

In `webpack.config.js` if you have a similar line like the following:

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
```

1. You have to remove:

   ```
   include: /ClientApp/
   ```
2. Make sure of the Environment, is it Development in `launchSettings.json` 
   like the following lines:

   ```
   "environmentVariables": {
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
     },
   ```

Comment: With dev environment, everything works fine as mentioned. also this question is not longer valid as with the latest upgraded framework template, angular cli is used and we don't see the issue mentioned

Answer (score -3):

@Gurpreet,
To solve this common issue with .NET 2.0 SDK, unfortunately, it is not enough just remove `include: /ClientApp` from your webpack.config.js. You also need to replace the check for `isDevBuild` and leave the condition when `isDevBuild` is always `true`. So, in my case, I have this line in webpack.config.js, that didn't give me any errors when publishing to Azure:
`{ test: /\.ts$/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] },`